# How to subtract two string values in java

Tags: java, android

Am having two string contaning integer values how can i subtract this to string.

```
 String addquantity = quantity1.getText().toString();
 String subquantity = quantity2.getText().toString();
 int final_ = Integer.parseInt(addquantity) - Integer.parseInt(subquantity);
```

I tried many methods but its showing error , help me to subtract the value in string.

Comment: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "null"

Comment: quantity1 and quantity2 containing the integer value like 3 ,5

Comment: please check if quantity1 or quantity2 are not null

Comment: Maybe your EditTexts are not initialized yet, something like "quantity1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.YOUR_EDIT_TEXT_ID)" you need for both

Comment: @MounirElfassi, if they were null, he would get a NullPointerException on line 1 or 2

Comment: post more code please.

Comment: is there any invalid char? for example: \n

Comment: Yes mounir & manuel , you are correct i forgot to get the value of edittext which is declared inside the loop.

Comment: I already post the correct answer so you can upvote for it, glad to know it's working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your EditTexts are not initialized, you need something like `quantity1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.YOUR_EDIT_TEXT_ID)` for both.

Answer (score 0):

Check what you are passing...check my example.

```
package general;

public class TestNumberFormat {

    public static void main(String[] args){
     String addquantity = "40";
     String subquantity = "30";
     int final_ = Integer.parseInt(addquantity) - Integer.parseInt(subquantity);
     System.out.println("PRINT :" + final_);

     String addquantity1 = "D40";
     String subquantity1 = "D30";
     int final1_ = Integer.parseInt(addquantity1) - Integer.parseInt(subquantity1);
     System.out.println("PRINT :" + final1_);

  }
}
```

Output:

PRINT :10

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "D40"  
at       java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)  
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
at general.TestNumberFormat.main(TestNumberFormat.java:13)
```

Comment: Even a space can lead to issues. use trim()

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you got an  space in your string.
Use following

```
String addquantity = quantity1.getText().toString().trim();
String subquantity = quantity2.getText().toString().trim();
```

Comment: trim() does not solve the problem because the problem is one or both are null.